# Android Studio ADB wipes out logcat files when app crashes! Ohh Myy

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Just upgraded latest Android Studio. Now when app crashes, the log files adb logcat disappear. It not only stops recording the whole logs seems to be suddenly wiped out.  Not too cool for debugging. Do I need to set log cache size or something? Also noticed that debugger takes a very long time to collect its data, but this might be specific to the program I am testing.

Comment: It's probably not actually *clearing* the logs themselves, but just not displaying in a way you like. Try running the adb logcat program from the command line if you would like to view it differently.

Comment: yeah thats right @Chris Stratton, I would prefer not to see the logs suddenly zoom up up and away while I am trying to read them.

Answer (score 68):

When I use Android Studio I face the same problem, I resolve this problem by a simple solution: **Set the logcat filter**:

1. Click Edit Filter Configuration at right of logcat
   [image]
2. in the package name field, set you application ID, and click OK.
   [image]

Next time the app crash, the logcat will not wipes out.

Very Glad my reputation is above 10, and I can add photo in my answer directly.

Comment: Works!! +1 but so weird android studio. hard to figure it out :-/

Comment: For some reason this solution worked for me only after I closed and reopened the Android Studio